# Train Wav2Vec-U for a custom dataset

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, fairseq

I found the github repo of [Wav2Vec-U](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/tree/master/examples/wav2vec/unsupervised), but it is not well-documented. I wonder if there is any train procedure for it. I'm trying to train it on common voice audios. But it needs wrd, ltr, and phn files, which I don't have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the best (only?) relevant writeup is [this notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/jimregan/wav2vec-u-cv-swedish-audio?scriptVersionId=64309738) hosted on Kaggle. In the comments section of that notebook, there is a link to [another notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/jimregan/wav2vec-u-cv-swedish-prep-ltr-phn-wrd) which is specifically relevant to the `wrd, ltr, and phn files` part of your question.